# How can I deserialize this json string with gson?

Tags: android, json, gson

I am trying to deserialize this JSON string in an Android project but I have no experience in it whatsoever.

```
{"nodes":[{"node":{"title":"esesese", "body":"hey world whatup"}}, {"node":{"title":"Asdasd", "body":"asdefasdefe"}}]}
```

I was trying to do something like this, but it won't work:

```
public class Nodes {    
    public Node[] nodes;
}

public class Node {
    public String title;
    public String body;
}
```

With this code:

```
    Nodes articles = new Gson().fromJson(result, Nodes.class);
```

Comment: Answer from Ads seems to match your problem. I just want to add that your Json seems to be poorly designed - there is an unnecessary level in it's tree.

Comment: it is not my full json sadly :S

Comment: and I am not the one who is designing it, it does have an unnecessary layer in it. I need to work with it though :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works:

```
public static class Nodes {
    private List<NodeWrapper> nodes;

    public List<NodeWrapper> getNodes() {
        return nodes;
    }

    public void setNodes(List<NodeWrapper> nodes) {
        this.nodes = nodes;
    }
}

public static class Node {
    private String title;
    private String body;

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getTitle() { return title; }

    public void setBody(String body) { this.body = body; }

    public String getBody() { return body; }
}


public static class NodeWrapper {
    private Node node;

    public Node getNode() { return node; }

    public void setNode(Node node) { this.node = node; }
}
```

Then do

```
Nodes nodes = new Gson().fromJson(result, Nodes.class);
```

I tried it with this:

```
    Nodes nodes = new Gson().fromJson("{\"nodes\":[{\"node\":{\"title\":\"esesese\", \"body\":\"hey world whatup\"}}, {\"node\":{\"title\":\"Asdasd\", \"body\":\"asdefasdefe\"}}]}", Nodes.class);
    System.out.println(nodes.getNodes().get(1).getNode().getBody());
```

The reason why it is so roundabout is if you look at your JSON:

```
{
    "nodes": [
        {
            "node": {
                "title": "esesese",
                "body": "hey world whatup"
            }
        },
        {
            "node": {
                "title": "Asdasd",
                "body": "asdefasdefe"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Then `nodes` contains a list of objects that have a `node` property, which have a `title` and `body` property - it's not just a list of objects that contain a `title` and a `body`. Therefore, you need a wrapper around that.

Comment: Thank you! Both answers are correct, but yours is more in depth. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You can deserialize as

```
public class Nodes{
private List<Node> nodes = new ArrayList<Node>();
}

public class Node_ {
private String title;
private String body;
}

public class Node {
private Node_ node;
}
```

In Code try:

```
Nodes articles = new Gson().fromJson(result, Nodes.class);
```